# JAVA Lightest Thread Framework

Tags: java, multithreading, frameworks

I have a project where I have to send emails using Amazon SES REST API, now amazon allows concurrent connections at a same time based on account. So in my case amazon allows me to open 50 connections at a same time, which means I can send 50 emails/sec. To achieve this, currently I am using JAVA Executioner threads where I control the thread speed to be 50/sec. Also I have implemented this in Hibernate framework because I need to execute some SQL queries before sending emails.

This java program runs continuously in background(its a jar file). This takes around 512MB RAM, so my question is that can I use some other frameworks or better thread system to make it more lighter? The SQL query I execute is only a select query, update/delete/create queries are not used.

I am not good in JAVA so may be this sounds stupid.

Comment: Did you actually *configer* any memory settings? Without those Java's greedy.

Comment: drop the Hibernate and use direct JDBC. you can google for benchmarks

Comment: and depending on the use case, perhaps a cache layer is also in order

Comment: First of all you need to find wich process/objects taking sizeable amount of memory to focus in right direction. You can do it from memory dump

Comment: @Jan Yes I do, `nohup java -Xms512M -Xmx1G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar XYZ.jar`

Comment: Java 8 uses a new GC engine called G1. did you try it?

Comment: @MSach the major memory is taken by threads, because it opens HTTP connection with Amazon

Comment: please define "more lighter" where's the bottleneck??

Comment: You have exclusively set minimum memory with `-Xms512M ` switch, forcing application to reserve this much ram.

Comment: @VivekSingh I had to mention minimum as 512 because that much it requires, any thing less than that kills the program.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the smallest possible framework to use would be plain JDBC.

This would limit your libraries to those in the jre plus the DB driver and maybe libs for AWS / Email. Depending on what else you need, selecting a *[compact profile](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/tech/compact-profiles-overview-2157132.html)* might be worth investigating.

Also **check your memory settings**:

If you set -Xms512m it's *really* not surprising your app uses 512m, is it?

**Edit due to rephrased question**

In your level of parallelism, most of your Memory is consumed by *Objects*, not by *Threads* (well, Threads *are* objects, but small ones). Threads are good the way they are in Java. You can run hundrets of them *without* them consuming 500 mb of heap or more as you claim.

So the issue with 50 threads consuming 512m of your memory is more likely rooted in your code and your objects, not (only) in your threads.

In order to reduce memory footprint, tra the follwing:

- Remove hibernate. As you say you only have a simple select SQL, so you don't need the overhead and additional libraries.
- Take a memory dump of your running app and analyse it. ([MAT - Eclipse Memory Analyser](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) tool comes to mind)
- Check other objects and how you use them. When you say "sending emails" - how large are your emails? Might there be duplicate buffers do to bad choice of coding? Share your code for how you do it, then we can have a look.
- Try running *without* any memory options and see how the program runs on defaults.
- Add garbage collector output and check that

Comment: @ntechi, you asked for a "lighter" framework, so we all assumed you wanted better memory management. you need to better define the requirements

Comment: I had to mention minimum as 512 because that much it requires, any thing less than that kills the program. Let me reframe my question title

Comment: See my edit. If you want some help reducing your memory footprint, you need to share some code. Threads are cheap in java - that alone cannot be the issue here.